# C# - Validate a json against a Schema. Where the error occurs in the json?

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

in c# I validate a json with a json schema, using the library Newtonsoft.Json.

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson); 

JObject Json= JObject.Parse(json);

bool valid = Json.IsValid(schema);
```

It works fine, but the problem is that I don't understand where the errors occur in a simple way. My 'json' is only in one Line and I have a lot of property so it isn't immediate to find the position of the proprierty where the error occurs.

For example, I got the error:

```
'Invalid type. Expected String but got Null. Line 1, position 2221'
```

Is there a way to find the name of the property of my json  where the error occurs using the library Newtonsoft.Json?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You might consider trying https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Json in stead if you are able to. It is also free to use as opposed to being paid.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it, but unfortunaly I think it is more simple to use library Newtonsoft.Json, for me.

Comment: It might be easier for you to use Manatee.Json.  Here's the docs for the output formatting: https://gregsdennis.github.io/Manatee.Json/usage/schema/validation.html#examples-of-output).  As you can see you have some options, and you get a **lot** more information.